# unparsable piece of python code for a java developer

Tags: java, python

I am comming from the java world and I really have a hard time to understand the following piece of code.

```
sortIx=['a2', 'a4', 'a1', 'a3', 'a5']
cItems=[sortIx]
print cItems
while len(cItems)>0:
    cItems=[i[j:k] for i in cItems for j,k in ((0,len(i)/2), (len(i)/2,len(i))) if len(i)>1] 
    print cItems
```

What exactly does this line do `cItems=[i[j:k] for i in cItems for j,k in ((0,len(i)/2), (len(i)/2,len(i))) if len(i)>1]`? How would you write this in java (or scala or groovy)?

**EDIT**

Thx to Reblochon Masque i was able to understand this! If one is interested, translated into groovy the statement would be something like this:

```
cItems = cItems.findAll { it -> it.size() > 1}
               .collectMany { it -> [it.subList(0, it.size().intDiv(2)), it.subList(it.size().intDiv(2), it.size())] }
```

Comment: It's a list comprehension: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Comment: It's a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). The things `(0,len(i)/2)` and `(len(i)/2,len(i)`, and the thing containing those two, are [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) (essentially lightweight lists).

Comment: If this helps, try reading it out in your head and then re-coding it back into Python code. That's what I do with long list comprehensions.

Comment: That is actually very poor code, it fails the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does this line do?

```
cItems = [i[j:k] for i in cItems for j, k in ((0, len(i) / 2), (len(i) / 2, len(i))) if len(i) > 1]
```

It partitions each inner lists contained into `cItems` into two sublists of half the size (containing each half of the elements), except when the sublist contains only one element, then it is ignored.